# Google Charts, HighCharts or ChartJS Dual Axis Gantt Chart and Line Chart Visualization

Tags: highcharts, chart.js, gantt-chart, google-visualization

I am trying to create a dual axis gantt chart and line chart to display tasks on the left axis (gantt chart data) and numeric values on the right axis (line chart data). I want to use Google Charts, HighCharts, or chartJs for the visualization and don't know which one can pull this off, see the link/picture attached to the question for the visual I am trying to get close to. I can display each chart individually but not together as a combined, dual axis chart. I have tried all sorts of the combination chart configuration but nothing comes close to working. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Here are links to Google Charts, HighCharts combo chart and gantt chart demos:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

https://www.highcharts.com/gantt/demo

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That type of chart can be easily created using Highcharts. You can use `line` and `xrange` series types with two `yAxis`:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: [{
        categories: [...],
    }, {
        opposite: true
    }],
    series: [{
        type: 'xrange',
        data: [...]
        }
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [...]
    }]
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zv74tsoq/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! The magic is in the xrange chart type due to the gantt-like date range display. I am digging deeper into the xrange configuration options now.